show_labels=False, show_conf=False parameters won't work (ultralytics==8.2.25)
Im using YOLO (v8.2.25) and when I run the code below it won't work:
model = YOLO(model_path)
results = model.predict(self.image_path, show_labels=False, show_conf=False)
result[0].save(filename=path_jpg_image)

The predictions are working OK, however even though I've set show_labels and show_conf are set to FALSE, the resulting image has the labels and confidence level.
Any suggestion to fix this?
Thanks

Environment details:
Ultralytics YOLOv8.2.25  Python-3.11.9 torch-2.3.0+cpu CPU (11th Gen Intel Core(TM) i5-1135G7 2.40GHz)
Setup complete ✅ (8 CPUs, 15.7 GB RAM, 220.0/237.8 GB disk)

OS Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
Environment Windows
Python 3.11.9
Install pip
RAM 15.73 GB
CPU 11th Gen Intel Core(TM) i5-1135G7 2.40GHz
CUDA None

matplotlib ✅ 3.9.0>=3.3.0
opencv-python ✅ 4.9.0.80>=4.6.0
pillow ✅ 10.3.0>=7.1.2
pyyaml ✅ 6.0.1>=5.3.1
requests ✅ 2.32.3>=2.23.0
scipy ✅ 1.13.1>=1.4.1
torch ✅ 2.3.0>=1.8.0
torchvision ✅ 0.18.0>=0.9.0
tqdm ✅ 4.66.4>=4.64.0
psutil ✅ 5.9.8
py-cpuinfo ✅ 9.0.0
thop ✅ 0.1.1-2209072238>=0.1.1
pandas ✅ 2.2.2>=1.1.4
seaborn ✅ 0.13.2>=0.11.0


The results can be plotted and saved without labels in at least two separate ways. The first way is to do it as a part of the model.predict() function:
# show_labels=False, show_conf=False will work with the save=True parameter
results = model.predict(self.image_path, show_labels=False, show_conf=False, save=True)

The second way is more convenient if you need to set the saved image name:
results = model.predict(self.image_path)
# add the labels=False parameter to hide this redundant information
results[0].save(filename=path_jpg_image, labels=False)

